# JqGrid column chooser add all and remove all functionality fails in internet explorer and firefox while working in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, jqgrid

JqGrid column chooser add all column and remove all column not working properly in ie and firefox.

Go to http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html select version 3.6 from left side and select column chooser.

when open column chooser selection box and click on remove all columns all column moved to left side. Now click on add all, all column should be moved in right side. But it not happened.

Answer (score 0):

Why one should use some retro version of jqGrid? I created the demo below which use the current 4.11.1 version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), the fork of jqGrid which I develop. You can try it by changing URLs of jqGrid to the URLs described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs).

Try [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/kvtrtzc5/6/) which use some fixed value for the width

```js
width: 560
```

it prevent collapsing of the grid width in case of removing of all columns. After removing all columns you can add the columns back without any problems. You can uncomment the column `name: "act"` in `colModel` and in `colNames` or to add `rownumbers: true` option which add fixed columns, which will be not hidden by column chooser. The results stay the same. I can't reproduce any problems.

Thus I recommend you to use the latest version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It should solve the problem.

Comment: I can not use latest version of jqgrid due to some compatibility issues. Is there any solution with jqgrid version 4.6.0????

Comment: @NitinPrajapati: **Which one compatibility issues you have? I can help you here.** Typically one need include 1-2 lines in your old code to fix the problems. In any way you should clear understand the problem: you ask me to create a workaround for the problem which not exist more. It's the main problem in the usage of free products. **Nobody will create for you only an individual solution *for free* if the problem is already known and already solved in the next version**.

Comment: I can not use latest version cause it is a very old product in which i am using jqgrid. If i use latest version of jqgrid i have to test my whole product that will take too more time. I want to solve my problem in same version of jqgrid i.e. 4.6.0.